# Update SQL Server  cell data with the data of next record

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update

I have to update the data of one of my SQL Server table that was mistakenly updated, and this caused data of one row's cell to over-write the next. Following is an example of what the table should have been in correct state:

```
FirstName      LastName     EmailID
--------------------------------------------------
abc            xyz          abc.xyz@something.com
def            321          def.321@something.com
ghi            123          ghi.123@something.com
```

Mistakenly the data has become:

```
FirstName   LastName    EmailID
---------------------------------------------
abc         xyz         something
def         321         abc.xyz@something.com
ghi         123         def.321@something.com
```

I know that the last one record will not be found but atleast other should be restored correctly

Comment: What are the primary keys? Only EmailID you need to update?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need any of the messy `&nbsp;` tags, either!

Comment: In order to answer this, you need to provide the key field.   SQL has no native concept of next in a table, you create that concept with  a primary key.

Comment: The table does not have a primary key. Though, has 2 candidate keys, `DomainID` and `PersonID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your table is ordered by firstName, lastName you can use this:

```
declare @contact as table (firstName varchar(255), lastName varchar(255), emailID varchar(255))
insert into @contact (firstName, lastName, emailID)
values
    ('abc', 'xyz', 'something')
    ,('def', '321', 'abc.xyz@something.com')
    ,('ghi', '123', 'def.321@something.com');


with contactCTE(rowNo, firstName, lastName, emailID) 
as
(
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY firstName, lastName DESC)
        ,firstName 
        ,lastName 
        ,emailID 
    from
        @contact 
)
update c1   
set
    emailID = c2.emailID 
from 
    contactCTE c1
    inner join contactCTE c2 on c1.rowNo +1 = c2.rowNo;

select * from  @contact
```

If your data is ordered differently just modify the `ORDER BY` part in `contactCTE` to reflect this